# Get string from txt file using byte code

Tags: java, android, string, file

```
String mail= "username@mail.com";               
byte[] mailByte = mail.getBytes();
String mailBytetoString = mailByte.toString();
File f2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Android/Data/Settings/mail.txt");
                        if(!f2.exists())
                            f2.createNewFile();
                        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f2));
                        br.write(mailBytetoString);
                        br.close();
```

I'm saving byte code of e-mail address to a txt file but I have to get it (e-mail address) again from txt file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That will never work... you need to construct a new String from the Array...

```
String myEmail = new String(mailByte);
```

Comment: No. I mean i am saving to txt file with this code and i want to read from txt file in another class. there is byte code in txt and i want to get string again from byte code. Is it possible?